# ClassNotFoundException even after adding jar file for jdbc connection

Tags: mysql, jdbc

i tried readding the jar files still it is throwing ClassNotFoundException.It is not a web project, it is simple java project. [error even after jar file for jdbc connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7xFL.png){}[Readded the jar file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1Rp0.png).Despite readding the necessary JAR files, a ClassNotFoundException persists in my simple Java project. This project doesn't involve web development; it's a straightforward Java application. I'm seeking assistance to resolve this issue and ensure the correct class loading during runtime.                                                                                 .

Comment: The problem is that you're not handling the checked exception thrown by `Class.forName`. You either need to wrap this in a try-catch, or add a `throws` clause. That said, you don't need to use `Class.forName` here. The driver will be loaded by automatic driver-loading.